# How to define the input image format for imagemagick convert?

Tags: svg, imagemagick

**How to define the input image format** for imagemagick `convert`, if `convert -identify` can't identify the input format by content, but I know it format well, and I can define it directly?

For example, I want to convert the svg file to png, but I have an example of valid svg which can't be identified by content.

Step to reproduce

1. Take this valid https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Svg.svg
2. Rename file `Svg.svg` to `image`
3. Try to `convert image image.png`
4. Got the

   *convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat ' @ error/constitute.cReadImage/501.*

ImageMagick version is 6.9.2-0 Q16 x86 2015-08-15

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/2053537/tnylee for correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this - you need to tell ImageMagick what to expect with the `svg:` prefix as it can't work out what is coming from the extension since there isn't one:

```
curl https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Svg.svg > image

convert svg:image image.png
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it